Error: Error: Dart library 'dart:js_interop_unsafe' is not available on this platform
/C:/Users/ravir/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pointycastle-3.8.0/lib/src/platform_check/node_crypto.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:js_interop_unsafe' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:js_interop_unsafe';
       ^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:js_interop_unsafe' is imported through these packages:

    web_entrypoint.dart => package:nrm_guide => package:pdf => package:image => package:archive => package:pointycastle => dart:js_interop_unsafe
    ...

Detailed import paths for (some of) the these imports:

    web_entrypoint.dart => package:nrm_guide/main.dart => package:nrm_guide/dashboard.dart => package:pdf/widgets.dart => package:pdf/src/widgets/annotations.dart => package:pdf/pdf.dart => package:pdf/src/pdf/document.dart => package:pdf/src/pdf/graphic_state.dart => package:pdf/src/pdf/obj/smask.dart => package:pdf/src/pdf/graphics.dart => package:pdf/src/pdf/obj/image.dart => package:image/image.dart => package:image/src/command/command.dart => package:image/src/filter/dither_image.dart => package:image/src/image/image.dart => package:image/src/image/icc_profile.dart => package:archive/archive.dart => package:archive/src/util/aes.dart => package:pointycastle/api.dart => package:pointycastle/src/registry/registry.dart => package:pointycastle/src/registry/registration.dart => package:pointycastle/export.dart => package:pointycastle/impl.dart => package:pointycastle/ecc/api.dart => package:pointycastle/ecc/ecdh.dart => package:pointycastle/ecc/ecc_base.dart => package:pointycastle/src/utils.dart => package:pointycastle/src/platform_check/platform_check.dart => package:pointycastle/src/platform_check/web.dart => package:pointycastle/src/platform_check/node_crypto.dart => dart:js_interop_unsafe

This error is happenig when I am using the pdf package for a flutter web application. Please help me with this thanks.

Does this answer your question? Flutter build error: 'dart:js_interop' is not available on this platform

i have read this but  was unable to resolve the issue

It is some junk file problem
I saw a folder name with some screenshots in the terminal. Just go to that folder and delete those files. (I forget the path to that)
or I think, close Android studio run %temp% on Windows search, and delete all junk files from there.
